# Is it possible to open a remote MDB Access database using VBScript without mapping the folder as a network drive?

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, remote-access

I wrote a VBScript program that runs on five computers running Windows 7 Pro X64.

This VBScript program needs to access to an MDB database (an Access 2000 database) stored on a computer on my LAN, and it contains sensible information.

At the moment my VBScript program works thanks to a hidden network drive that maps the folder containing the MDB file and that is mounted just for the time needed and after it is dismounted. I'd like to know if there is the possibility to access remotely the MDB file from the VBScript program using some ODBC or another driver .

Thanks for attention.

Comment: At some point in your code you presumably specify the path to the database file using the drive letter (e.g., `X:\folder\file.mdb`). Have you tried specifying a UNC path (e.g., `\\server\share\folder\file.mdb`) instead?

Comment: I've never tried it, but I think you can build a connection string for access on a samba share using the `\\servername\file\location.mdb` UNC type path. See [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) for examples.

Comment: If i use the UNC \\path I need to map it using valid credentials on the remote computer. It's like using network drive. Bye

Comment: Could you show your code? I had a similar problem some time ago but wasn't able to fix it. In the end I always ran my script on the machine where the DB was saved.

Comment: You don't want the db accessible by users outside the script? Protect it with a password, then you can provide a share to the file without users beeing able to open the db (unless they can't see the code of the script). If you want more security use a `dbms` like `MS-SQL` or `MySQL`.